# Laravel 8: Sorting grouped array by a nested column - what should I put into sortBy closure?

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I'm dealing with a specifically shaped array in Laravel where items are grouped by keys that represent names of categories.

In below example I have elements from categories `1`, `5` and `76`. Each element has a key called `order` which is a nullable integer that should indicate the order within this category.

```
array:3 [
  "category_1" => array:4 [
    1 => array:2 [
      "option_name" => "Some name 1"
      "option_items" => array:1 [
        0 => array:5 [
          "id" => 1
          "price" => 200
          "time" => 0
          "order" => 999
        ]
      ]
    ]
    2 => array:2 [
      "option_name" => "Some name 2"
      "option_items" => array:1 [
        0 => array:5 [
          "id" => 2
          "price" => 780
          "time" => 5
          "order" => null
        ]
      ]
    ]
    3 => array:2 [
      "option_name" => "Some name 3"
      "option_items" => array:1 [
        0 => array:5 [
          "id" => 3
          "price" => 400
          "time" => 4
          "order" => null
        ]
      ]
    ]
    4 => array:2 [
      "option_name" => "Some name 4"
      "option_items" => array:1 [
        0 => array:5 [
          "id" => 4
          "price" => 300
          "time" => 2
          "order" => 434
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
  "category_5" => array:2 [
    6 => array:2 [
      "option_name" => "Some name 5"
      "option_items" => array:1 [
        0 => array:5 [
          "id" => 6
          "price" => 890
          "time" => 3
          "order" => null
        ]
      ]
    ]
    7 => array:2 [
      "option_name" => "Some name 6"
      "option_items" => array:1 [
        0 => array:5 [
          "id" => 7
          "price" => 1290
          "time" => 5
          "order" => null
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
  "category_76" => array:2 [
    10 => array:2 [
      "option_name" => "Some name 7"
      "option_items" => array:1 [
        0 => array:5 [
          "id" => 10
          "price" => 320
          "time" => 4
          "order" => 33
        ]
      ]
    ]
    11 => array:2 [
      "option_name" => "Some name 8"
      "option_items" => array:2 [
        0 => array:5 [
          "id" => 11
          "price" => 600
          "time" => 0
          "order" => 500
        ]
        1 => array:5 [
          "id" => 12
          "price" => 2000
          "time" => 9
          "order" => 500
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
]
```

I simply want to sort this entire array per category by order key ascending (with nulls at the end), so for example the **order of elements in `category_1` would be**:

1. Some name 4 (order of `434`)
2. Some name 1 (order of `999`)
3. Some name 2 (order is nor present / null)
4. Some name 3 (same as above)

> What did you try?

Obviously I've tried converting this plain PHP array to collection and calling `sortBy` with a closure via:

```
$sorted = collect($array)->sortBy(function ($elementsInCategory, $key) {
    dd($elementsInCategory); // $key is category_1
})->toArray();
```

but I simply don't know what to return from the callback to make it sort the way I've described.

BTW. I don't want to complicate too much but please notice that `option_items` sub-array may sometimes have more than one item (key `11` from `category_76`) but this does not matter - elements in this sub array will always have the same order value. This inner array should not be sorted - can be left as is.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Laravel collection macro for that

```
$Collection::macro('sortByOrder', function (string $column = 'order', bool $descending = false) {
                /* @var $this Collection */

                return $this->sortBy(function ($order) use ($column) {

                    return strtotime(((object)$order)->$column);

                }, SORT_REGULAR, $descending);

            });
```

And you can use it like

```
 $categories->sortByOrder('order',false);
```